# Why $\langle u,v \rangle=\Re\langle u,v \rangle+i\;\Im\langle u,v \rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a complex inner product space. Why does $$\langle u,v \rangle=\Re\langle u,v \rangle+i\;\Im\langle u,v \rangle\;\text{?}$$

Answer (score 3):

I think you're overthinking this. $\langle u,v\rangle$ is just some complex number, call it $s$. $s=\Re(s)+i\cdot\Im(s)$ is automatically true.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I need some sleep. Thank u :)

Comment: @DanielCheca Don’t we all? ;) I can stare for ages at the simplest of statements when I’m tried